# SpriteKit origination and angle of gesture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, touches

I am very new to SpriteKit, so apologies for a beginner's question.

I have two objects from which a user can swipe into direction of a "target". I need to determine the origination point (that is from which of two objects the touch was originated) and the swipe angle.

I can use touchesBegan and touchesEnded to calculate those myself, but wonder if there is any other way to do it with sprites.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a different way? It works as you describe... Shows where you start, and where you end. Easy to calculate a vector between the two points.

Comment: Perhaps Alex wants something _more_ to his object movements :) see my answer.

Comment: Kendel, I did not need a different way, just did not want to code for something that has a ready solution, seems like this is the easiest way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always *another* way of doing something--this is programming! But, as Rube Goldberg demonstrates below, another way may not be the best / easiest way:

[image]

Using `touchesEnded` you are making sort of like a 'fling' gesture, which can be somewhat limited in it's capabilities.

Example, If you want the object to continuously gain velocity at some f of x / make small path changes (without necessarily having to lift the finger), you can use `touchesMoved`. Fill it with whatever calculations / functions you like.

## Example: drag a node with your touch:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    //-Main touch processoereor
    for touch in touches {
        
        let TPOINT  = touch.locationInNode(self)
        my_super_cool_node!.position = TPOINT
        
        // Put math stuff here, etc.
        
    }
}
```

This gives you MUCH more control over what happens to your sprite from point A to point B.

Here is a good tutorial:

http://www.globalnerdy.com/2016/02/02/writing-ios-games-with-swift-and-sprite-kit-part-2-responding-to-touches/

And Apple's stuff:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent:

Unfortunately, the best things in SpriteKit are going to require some clever implementations / math, and can't all be done with the Scene Editor and and nodes.

What you are talking about doing is a fairly routine (math) function, the distance formula, so it's pretty advantageous to make an actual `func` out of it, so that way you can customize it and not have to manually write a ton of a code for each thing you want to do.
SK makes things super easy already. Doing even the basic hello world with spinny spaceships would have been a thousand lines of code (or more) back in the day with C++ Direct3d / OpenGL (and tons of advanced math).

The SK editor is great, and with a little bit of programming on the backend, you can actually make full games from just the editor.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using touchesBegan/Ended in my (simple) case, but I see your point that touchesMoved gives more control on the way.

Comment: @AlexZabrodskiy NP, i envisioned some kind of hockey or soccer(futbol) and I was thinking, what if he was trying to put some spin on it? touchesEnded wouldnt work xD (like a zigzag motion)